# Single encrypted system partition without any boot partition -- how is that possible?

Tags: boot, partition, virtual-machine, kvm

The partitioning of a virtual disk image of a Lubuntu KVM guest I recently installed looks like this:

```
# lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE      LABEL              UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs 
                                                                 0   100% /rofs
... SNIP ...

sr0    iso9660     Ubuntu 19.10 amd64 2019-10-17-12-53-34-00                     0   100% /cdrom
vda                                                                                       
└─vda1 crypto_LUKS                    xxxx-yyyy-zzzz
```

In other words, it has one single encrypted system partition (`vda1`) and no boot partition. (NB. I booted into a live image to examine/resize the encrypted partition, and I was surprised by the lack of boot partition.)

**Question**: *how can the system manage to boot up (because it does boot up!) in spite of no boot partition?*

Follow-up questions for my better understanding:

- Does boot work, because KVM manages the decryption itself?
- Or, would this work on a host system too?
- If it would work on a stand-alone setup too, why do we ever create the (unencrypted) boot partition at all, and not just the standalone encrypted partition, like this?
- If it is KVM that manages the decryption, then what ensures that KVM has the correct/compatible version of `cryptsetup` installed, that was used to create the encrypted device? What if the version does not match?
- If it is KVM that manages the decryption, then I assume, that at the time of installing Lubuntu with full disk encryption, install noticed that it was running in a VM, and decided that creating a single encrypted partition would be enough. Is this the case? And if so, why didn't it ask if I want the "normal" setup, with the boot partition?

Remark: indeed the gui for opening the encrypted disk on boot is rather spartan. It is a text-based gui, where I have **one single** attempt to enter the pass phrase to open the encrypted partition, without any feedback at all (the asterisks do not appear to show at least how many characters I entered). Before I was assuming the reason was that Lubuntu is simpler than Ubuntu, but now I suspect (as written above) that KVM manages the decryption itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities:

- no boot partition is required when using MBR/DOS partitioning, GRUB with cryptodisk support, and LUKS 1 (or LUKS 2 with PBKDF2 passphrase). Future versions of GRUB might support LUKS 2 fully but afaik it's not quite there yet ([no argon2i support as of yet](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55093)).
- kernel/initramfs may be stored externally and loaded directly by qemu/KVM by passing appropriate `-kernel -initrd` options to qemu. In this case qemu itself acts as the boot loader so there is no need for a boot partition inside the VM either.
- The kernel image may exist at a specific device offset before the first partition - not a partition / filesystem / file but directly written as raw data to the device, and the bootloader knows where to look for it. This approach is usually seen on embedded devices only.

---

> why do we ever create the (unencrypted) boot partition at all, and not just the standalone encrypted partition, like this?

The problem is that bootloader has to go somewhere after all, and so with MBR/DOS partitioning a lot of that went on in unpartitioned space. Sure that can work ... until two different things try to place their data at the same offset and overwrite each other, anyway.

It was decided that it's nicer to have proper partitions for these. So with GPT you get an EFI partition, and/or GRUB gets a bios_grub partition for its core image, and so on.

Ideally you can then look at the partition table and kind of know how it's set up, and not scratch your head and ask here how things even work because it's all tucked away and hidden outside of the partitioning somewhere.

Comment: For the first option: where is GRUB itself then, if there is no boot partition? And if this is possible, then why is normally a boot partition created?

Comment: @Attilio added another comment, not sure if that helps. grub (the part that handles decryption) would have been in unpartitioned space before the 1st partition in that case

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point indeed! Is there any way/tool to check if the boot loader is indeed installed in the empty space before `vda1`?